# How to pick the first zipped item? | python |

Tags: python, list

```
import itertools  

a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6]
for i, j in zip(a,b):
    print(i,j)
```

Output:

```
1,4
2,5
3,6
```

But how to print only the first item from the output?

Expected output:

```
1,4
```

Comment: Why not just have `print(a[0], b[0])`?

Comment: You could also use a `break`, but it does not look like a good solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to pick the first element from any iterable, use [next](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next):

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6]

res = next(zip(a, b))
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
(1, 4)
```

It even let you define a default value for when the iterable is empty, from the documentation:

> If default is given, it is returned if the iterator is exhausted,
> otherwise StopIteration is raised.

For example:

```
res = next(zip([], b), 'empty')
print(res)
```

**Output** *(for default=empty)*

```
empty
```

For more complex cases of selecting elements from an iterable based on index, see the documentation on [itertools.islice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice).

Answer (score 0):

This works, but probably is not the most elegant.

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6]
for i, j in zip(a,b):
    print(i,j)
    break
```